# can't get value of select element with jquery

Tags: jquery

Have some form with values.

```
<script>
$("#save").click(function(){
    var name=$("#name").val();
    var adress=$("#adress").val();
    var contacts=$('#contacts').val();
    var headPhysician=$('#headPhysician').val();
    var chamber=$["#chamber option:selected"].text();
    var registrationDate=$["#registrationDate"].val();
    form={name:name,adress:adress,contacts:contacts,headPhysician:headPhysician,chamber:chamber,registrationDate:registrationDate}
    $.ajax({
        url : "addLPU.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : form,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {

        },
        });
});
</script>
<div id="lpuName" class="span12">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span6">Полное наименование больницы</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input id="name"class="span6"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="adressContats" class="span12">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span8">Адрес</p>
        <p class="span4">Все контакты</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input id="adress" class="span8" value="ул. Полковая 94"></input>
        <input id="contacts"  class="span4" value="89012983222"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mainDoctor">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span4">Имя главного врача</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input id="headPhysician" class="span5" value="Иванов Иван Иванович"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span5">Членство в медпалате</p>
        <p class="span3">Когда зарегистрировался как член медпалаты</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <select id="chamber" class="span5 selectpicker" value="По медицинской этике">
            <option>По медицинской этике</option>
            <option>по правовым вопросам и независимой экспертизе в сфере здравоохранения</option>
            <option>по образованию и науке в сфере здравоохранения</option>
            <option>контрольно-дисциплинарный</option>
            <option>по социальной поддержке и защите интересов медицинских работников</option>
            <option>по развитию рынка услуг в сфере здравоохранения</option>
            <option>по молодежной политике и поддержке медицинских специалистов</option>
        </select>
        <input id="registrationDate" class="span3" value="1970-11-01"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="buttons" class="span12">
    <a href="#" id="save" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Сохранить</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Отменить</a>
</div>
```

For some reason it says in string

```
var chamber=$["#chamber option:selected"].text();
```

That property text is not defined. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need round braces instead of square braces for jquery selector.

**Correct Way:** `$(...)`.

Try this:

```
  $("#chamber option:selected").text();
```

Comment: as mentioned in title I guess OP wants `value` instead of `text`

Comment: @Karna: if you look carefully at the DOM, options do not have value attribute.

Comment: Yup. But title seems misleading to me

Comment: A more interesting question would be why your answer is upvoted when none of the others are ?

Comment: @adeneo may be because he pin pointed the cause instead of just giving the solution

Comment: @adeneo he added `round braces instead of square braces for jquery selector` instead of just giving the solution.

Comment: @Karna - And that's different from my answer and T McKeowns answer how exactly ?

Comment: @adeneo yup. Actually you answered 1 second before Milind. Dont know whats going on in upvoters mind

Comment: It's not that I really care, it's just interesting that all the upvotes go to the second answer posted when there are three equal answers, and the two other answers get no upvotes at all (I upvoted T McKeown).

Comment: @adeneo: this is something not new to us here(LOL happening every other day to me). when someone up votes one vote, others keep voting the same without referring other answer.

Comment: Yes, I see it all the time as well, and again, it's not about the votes, I'm already over the 200 limit so it doesn't matter, it's just interesting that three people upvote this particular answer, when it's not the first one posted, and there are two other answers that are exactly the same. I guess it's just my curiosity, but I can't understand why people just upvote without reading all the answers, and if they did, why not upvote all the answers ?

Answer (score 1):

It's parenthesis, not brackets, as `$()` is a function

```
var chamber = $("#chamber option:selected").text();
```

and if you wrap your code in a form tag, you can just do

```
var form = $('form').serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `[` and `]` to `(` and `)` on **all** your jQuery code.

```
var chamber=$("#chamber option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want *value* (as mentioned in title) instead of *text* you should use

```
$("#chamber").val();
```

This will give `value` of selected option while

```
$("#chamber option:selected" ).text();
```

will give *text* of selected option.
[**This**](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var chamber=$("#chamber option:selected").text();
    var registrationDate=$("#registrationDate").val();
```